# Generate an HTML table with dynamic row Height

Tags: php, html

I need to print an html table with row heights sets dynamically based on some values from the database using PHP. seems that html 5 doesn't support inline height and with tags and using css instead. 
My requirement is to generate an html file and then  convert it into pdf using DOM pdf.

Please guide  me how to set these parameters dynamically inline or using css or whether a library already available for the same purpose.

I Googled a lot, but unable  find any results matching my requirement. 
Also am attaching final output format

(In answer column i printed some values which is the height required for each row)[image: Sample Output]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share your code here, what you tried?

Comment: @JoeBuckle yes of course.. Is there any library for that ?

Comment: do you really need fixed heights? Table-rows advance automatically in height if you put some content in.

Comment: @BastianRang check the attached image. Some answer columns requires more space so i need to adjust the height as such. SO it doesn't depend on the content height(ie,question column)

Answer (score 1):

You can use inline styles:

`<tr style="height: 300px;"></tr>`

I am not sure if you can effectively set the height of a `<tr>` tag, so you might have to set the height of each `<td>` in the row individually. Give it a try.

Furthermore, I am not sure how you have your array of rows and columns structured, but this might shed some light on how to do it.

```
<?php
$array=array(array(50,'r1c1','r1c2'),array(50,'r2c1','r2c2'));
echo '<table>';
foreach($array as $row)
{
    echo '<tr style="height: '.$row[0].'px;">';
    echo '</tr>';
    for($i=1;$i<count($row);++$1)
    {
        echo '<td>'.$row[$i].'</td>';
    }
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

If you still need help, post the exact array you wish to turn into a `<table>` and I will do my best to assist.

Comment: I already shared required table output image with my query. Please refer the image. :) hope it's clear from that image

Comment: @CodeinDreams Well, I see the image of course, but that still doesn't say exactly what your array looks like. The array is what is important here, as it dictates how the loops are created. From there you can adjust to dictate how the output looks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this right, your table rows can be different sizes from each other, but for each row there is a rule in database, that sets row's height, no matter what height the content of the row, right? Then you can use something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        <?php foreach($yourRows as $key => $row) { ?>
            #row<?=$key;?>{
                height: <?=$row['height']; ?>px;
            }
        <?php } ?>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
    <?php foreach($yourRows as $key => $row) { ?>
        <tr id="row<?=$key; ?>">
            ...
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </table>
</body>
```

In the style tag you can replace "`#row<?=$key;?>`" with "`#row<?=$key;?> td`"

```
Updated
```

Anyway, if you want to use the inline styling, you can make it happen like that:

```
<html>
<body>
    <table>
        <?php foreach($yourRows as $row) { ?>
                <tr style="height:<?=$row['height']; ?>px">
                    Or you can apply height to td instead of the tr...
                </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: In my opinion, this method pollutes the page's CSS with many rules that have to be matched, which potentially interfere with CSS elsewhere. I think inline styles are more appropriate here.

Comment: **teh1**, may be you right about that, but with that method you can also add inline styles - it's all about the code sample. I don't like that solution neither, but as **Code in Dreams** said, the inline styles not worked for him, so instead of searching possible issues, that preventing him from applying inline styles, i decided to make it easier, and to give him another solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you think that jQuery might work here is a suggestion. I'm not sure it works with DOMPDF but as we're dynamically creating CSS it should be fine once the DOM has loaded.

If you know exactly the heights of each row - then select them using jQuery using [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table tr').eq(1).css({'height':'250'});
    $('table tr').eq(3).css({'height':'450'});
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bambattajb/t5fCD/1/).

That way you don't have to modify the output but you have to make the assumption the content isn't going to be higher than your fixed height.

If you need this to be more dynamic then you'll need to either associate identifiers to your rows, like a class or something like that. Or alternatively, if you have a pattern in your content is to create a regular expression that scans your content and identifies it that way - then you can apply CSS rules to these rows once matched using jQuery.

**EDIT**

OK so I may have slightly misunderstood if you have the height value stored in the database. It also looks as though you've determined already that you're unable to use inline styles.

Here is my next suggestion.

You're building the table from a loop so it probably looks something like this.

```
foreach($rows as $row) {
  echo '<tr data-height="'.$row['height'].'"><td>...</td></tr>;
}
```

if you add **data-height="'.$row['height'].'"** then you have a value that we can get using jQuery's [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) like so.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table tr').each(function() {
        var height = $(this).data('height');
        $(this).css({ 'height': height });
    });
});
```

Here is an example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bambattajb/vSLcq/) with static data-height values. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: content height never go higher than the fixed height. Minimum height is the content height. If the required height for a row is more than the content height , then it should be based on the database **height field** value. Is there any way to feed height values dynamically to the given code ?

Comment: Is the database height field stored in a PHP variable?

Comment: I'll add an edit as soon as I'm in the office. I have an idea